# Python folium map developement

Tags: python, maps, folium

I am trying to build a map on python and i am using the folium library.I can see the map on my browser when it is only:

```
import folium
map = folium.Map(location=[25.747608, 89.268044])
map.save("Map2.html")
```

When i add two more parameters like (tiles="Mapbox Bright") and (zoom_start=6) my code looks like this and the map does not work :

```
import folium
map = folium.Map(location=[25.747608, 89.268044], zoom_start=6, tiles="Mapbox Bright")
map.save("Map2.html")
```

What can i do with my code so that i see the map in my browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried it too, neither the Mapbox Bright or Mapbox Control Room tiles seem to work, I don't think they're supported anymore. Try any of the other tiles or don't specify a tile parameter and it should work fine.

Here's a list of available tiles:
https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an API_key to view the map in your browser. Or you can use other tiles like 'Stamen Toner', 'OpenStreetMap', 'Stamen Toner', 'Stamen Watercolor'.

Comment: I'll have to check them out,

Comment: How do i add Api_keys?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML in your map in order to add any text in the map

```
    legend_html =   '''
                    <div style="position: fixed; 
                bottom: 50px; right: 50px; width: 150px; height: 90px; 
                border:2px solid grey; z-index:9999; font-size:14px;
                ">&nbsp; Legend <br>
                &nbsp; Origin &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x" style="color:green"></i><br>
                &nbsp; Destination &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x" style="color:blue"></i>
                    </div>
                '''

map_m.get_root().html.add_child(folium.Element(legend_html))
```

Comment: I was using python to create the map. i am not sure where i can put this code.

Comment: This example is also in python, the part of the  legend_html is HTML sentences, for example, <div style ... give you the position that will be add in the map with the bottom, right, width and height you can change that, the import part the "&nbsp" there you can add the text or icons, for example this code add a marker and a text "Origin", "Destination"